# regex'es to validate these

Tags: regex, validation

regexes?

to validate a name with only characters and spaces e.g.

```
Jon Skeet
```

to validate a number having digits and dashes anywhere e.g.

```
423-4324234-423
4233-412341324
```

Comment: What do you already have? What are the requirements for your name / number strings?

Comment: What characters do you allowed in a name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic english name:

```
([a-zA-Z]+\s*)+
```

Numbers with dashes anywhere except for beginning and end:

```
\d[-\d]+\d
```

Numbers with dashes anywhere:

```
[-\d]+
```

**Edit:**

If you are looking for name inside of a sentence, such as

> Hello, my name is John Doe.

You can try and capture names based on two or more capitalized words in a row.

```
([A-Z][A-Za-z]+\s*){2,}
```

Comment: Validate it here http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html worked fine for me with your examples.

Answer (score 1):

`Jon Skeet`

```
/([a-zA-Z ]+)/
```

`423-4324234-423`
`4233-412341324`

```
/([\d-]+)/
```

Answer (score 1):

To match a name in any language :

```
/^[\p{L} '-]+$/
```

That matches O'Connors Anne-Marie El Niño ...

to match your example digits:

```
/^[\d-]+$/
```